# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG has been compiled by more recent version of the Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

```
`at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

`Getting this exception while executing the program . Currently I am using JDK Ver-20, JRE ver-1.8 [SS FYR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unWxA.png)
[SS FYR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz1xZ.png)

I changed the prefrences version but still getting same issue

Comment: The error indicates you're actually running with Java 8.

Comment: Your Testng libraries are compiled for Java 11 so you're going to have to build with at least that version (or get an earlier build of Testng)